# ./a.out: file not recognized: File truncated collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status?

Tags: c

I wrote a small program that fills an array with prime numbers which are returned from a separate function. The program compile fine but when i go to run the executable i get the above error. Here is my source code. I'm not really sure why its happening. Could anyone here do me the huge favor of compiling and running the following code? I'm wondering if its something on my laptop but i really have no clue. I'm running linux mint if that helps at all.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int prime(int x);

int main()
{
    int intergers,index,return_value;
    int array[100]={2};                                           /*intialize array[0] being 2*/

    for(index=1;index<100;index=index+1)                          /*begin array index at array[1]*/
    {
        for(intergers=3;intergers<102;intergers=intergers+1)      /*check for prime numbers starting from 3*/
        {
            return_value = prime(intergers);

            if(return_value==999)
                array[index]=-1;
            else
                array[index]=return_value;
        }
    }
    printf("hello world");
}

int prime(int x)
{
    int divisors,count,value;

    for(divisors=2;divisors<x;divisors=divisors+1)
    {
        if(x%divisors==0)
        {
            value=999;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            value=x;
        }

    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Works for me. How do you compile it? Do you get any errors while compiling? Do you have free drive space?

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful if you edited the question, adding information about how you compiled the program.  ie: "gcc -Wall ..."?

Comment: ok it compiles now, but it cant be executed. i just did gcc array.c using the linux mint termial and when i execute the created ./a.out profile i get that top error

Answer (score 0):

The following code compiled and linked without errors or warnings from the gcc compiler on SuSE SLES 11 using the following command: `gcc -Wall -o test test.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int prime(int x);

int main()
{
    int intergers,index,return_value;
    int array[100]={2};                                           /*intialize array[0] being 2*/

    for(index=1;index<100;index=index+1)                          /*begin array index at array[1]*/
    {
        for(intergers=3;intergers<102;intergers=intergers+1)      /*check for prime numbers starting from 3*/
        {
            return_value = prime(intergers);

            if(return_value==999)
                array[index]=-1;
            else
                array[index]=return_value;
         }
    }
    printf("hello world\n");

   return(0);  // Added this line to rid compiler: warning: control reaches end of non-void function 
}

int prime(int x)
{
    int divisors,/* count, */ value;

    for(divisors=2;divisors<x;divisors=divisors+1)
    {
        if(x%divisors==0)
        {
            value=999;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            value=x;
        }

    }
    return value;
}
```

I then executed the program:

```
> ./test
hello world
```

The code executed as expected.

Comment: once executed did it run fine because i get the eror on the file execution

Comment: thats so weird, im gonna compile like you did using that wall thing and try it again. Thanks, good to know it worked

Comment: ok it worked once i followed what you did. Thanks for the advice